# A question regarding sequence in the span

Tags: functional-analysis, c-star-algebras

I have the following problem:

> **Problem**: Suppose that $\pi$ is a nondegenerate representation of $A$ on $\mathcal{H}$. Let $\{e_\lambda\}$ be an approximate identity for $A$. Prove that $\lim_\lambda\pi(a)h=h$ for all $h\in\mathcal{H}$.

Now, the author states that $\pi$ is a nondegenerate representation of $A$ on $\mathcal{H}$ if
$$
[\pi(A)\mathcal{H}]:=
\overline{\text{span}}\{\pi(a)h:a\in A\text{ and }h\in\mathcal{H}\}=
\mathcal{H}.
$$

Then in the proof of the problem the author proceeds to say the following: "Let $h\in\mathcal{H}$ and $\epsilon>0$ be given. By assumption there are vectors $h_1,\dots,h_n\in\mathcal{H}$ and elements $x_1,\dots,x_n\in A$ such that $\|h-\sum_{i_1}^n\pi(x_i)h_i\|<\epsilon$." I do not see why this is true. I mean, I understand that for $h\in\mathcal{H}$ there is a sequence in $\text{span}\{\pi(a)h:a\in A\text{ and }h\in\mathcal{H}\}$ such converges to $h$. However, I do not understand why the author is saying that such a sequence is of the form $\sum_{i_1}^n\pi(x_i)h_i$.

Comment: Do you know what the span is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once again, I have difficulty locating the issue, so let me try to be very detailed.

Let $h \in \mathcal{H} = \overline{\operatorname{span}}\{\pi(a)h: a \in A, h \in \mathcal{H}\}$ and $\epsilon > 0$. Hence, there is $y \in \operatorname{span}\{\pi(a)h: a \in A, h \in \mathcal{H}\}$ such that $\|h - y\| < \epsilon$.

Now, by definition of the linear span, $$y = \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i\pi(a_i)h_i= \sum_{i=1}^n \pi(\lambda_i a_i)h_i$$ for certain $a_i \in A, h_i \in \mathcal{H}$ and $\lambda_i \in \mathbb{C}$.

Putting $x_i := \lambda_i a_i\in A$ gives the desired form.

Comment: I guess I don't understand why $y$ is not a sequence? For instance, let $A$ be some set and let $\overline{A}$ be its closure. Then $a\in\overline{A}$ means there is some sequence $a_n\in A$ for which $a_n\to a$, in whatever norm/metric $A$ is equipped with.

Comment: $a_n \to a$ means for all $\epsilon >0$ there is $n_0$ such that $\|a_n-a\| < \epsilon$ when $n \ge n_0$. This is what the author is using.

Comment: @D.Math If I may offer some unasked advice, brush up your background knowledge about analysis and algebra before you get serious about $C^*$-algebra theory, or you will have a miserable time.

Comment: Well, I know that is what the author is using. It just appears your $y$ is an element of the $\text{span}$, rather than a sequence in the $\text{span}$...perhaps I need sleep.

Comment: Elements in $\overline{X}$ can be approximated by elements in $X$. This is all that is used here.

Comment: Yeah, my apologies. I kept getting confused on something rather trivial. Ironically, for some reason, a lot of the "harder" material makes sense, whereas some of the "easier" things will confuse me. On top of that, I'm self studying...

Comment: D.Math We have all been there. It gets better.